# Is it OK to add session_start(); to the top of my entire website?

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I've been using the following code in our buying process section of our website by placing at the top of each stage where sessions are used.

```
   <?php
    session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire'); // must go before session start
    session_start();
```

I want to start using sessions more widely on the website, for instance in the customer login area.

I have a file called "all.php" which includes all my classes/objects and shared includes at the start of each page on my system. I thought removing the above code from all the separate e-commerce files and adding to the top of "all.php" would be a good idea seeing as it's system wide, and the first thing that loads on the page.

Since doing this, my customer login area has encountered problems. It keeps throwing users back to the login page after they've navigated a few links. It seems when you hit a URL that you've already been on it doesn't like it and just sends you back to the start. If you add &1=1 onto a url that you've been onto before, it tricks the system into letting you visit the page because its a new unique url. So the cache is definitely messing up.

I'm not actually using sessions in this section of the website yet so it's not like you are actually being logged out... it's just sending you to that page where you started,

Can anyone shed any light on what may be going wrong here?

Could it be my use of session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire');

I use the above line because my buying process uses POST forms and clicking the back button gave ugly messages about data being resubmitted.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php

UPDATE:

Commenting out that first line has helped and the issue has stopped:

```
//session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire'); // must go before session start
```

It's a temporary fix as this means the back button is causing data resubmission warnings. That just means I need to implementing this properly but I'd still ike to understand why that line is doing that:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: yes its ok to start at the top of the page till you use session

Comment: Session itself is not causing the redirect. You must have code there that does it.

Comment: We would need to see more of your code, but I don't see how `session_start()` could possibly be causing this issue. What I would recommend is if you're adding items to a shopping cart, redirect the user back to the specific product page after processing their action using `header()` - this also prevents them refreshing (and triggering a message about resubmitting form data) and they won't feel the need to press the back button (generally)

Comment: See my update. Any more thoughts much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the similar thing as we create a login panel in PHP. 
As soon as user is loged in you need to start the session by using session_start() and when the user click log out stop the session by using ssession_unset(). This will solve you  issues. 
Try it out and let me know if it works.

Keep Coding..

Comment: There is no such function in PHP as `session_stop()`. You need `session_destroy()`

Comment: Hello iamgory...!!! You can also use session unset. That session stop was my bad..

Answer (score 1):

The quickest and cleanest way to bypass this is to do this when done processing form data, instead of displaying information on the page that does the processing.

```
Header('Location: http://www.domain.com/page.php');
```

If, for example, you're adding an item to a shopping cart, redirect the user either to their cart page when done or to the item page again.

`Since doing this, my customer login area has encountered problems. It keeps throwing users back to the login page after they've navigated a few links. It seems when you hit a URL that you've already been on it doesn't like it and just sends you back to the start. If you add &1=1 onto a url that you've been onto before, it tricks the system into letting you visit the page because its a new unique url. So the cache is definitely messing up.`

`session_cache_limiter('private_no_expire')`. You don't need it  for what you're doing.